# How to convert from from ubuntu desktop 11.04 to ubuntu server 11.04

Tags: 11.04, server, convert

How to convert from from ubuntu desktop 11.04 to ubuntu server 11.04

What does the below command do?

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-server linux-image-server linux-server
```

Comment: Maybe you should split your question in two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## What's the difference between desktop and server?

**1)** The first difference is in the CD contents. The "Server" CD avoids including what Ubuntu considers desktop packages (packages like X, Gnome or KDE), but does include server related packages (Apache2, Bind9 and so on).

**2)** The Ubuntu Server Edition installation process is slightly different from the Desktop Edition. Since by default Ubuntu Server doesn't have a GUI, the process is menu driven, very similar to the Alternate CD installation process.

**3)** Ubuntu server installs a server-optimized kernel by default (the commands you mentioned should do it).

**4)** Ubuntu Desktop will receive 3 years of support, while Ubuntu Server will be supported for 5 years.

---

## Can I convert the Desktop installation to server?

You can use apt-get to install the packages you need like Apache and Bind9 for example.

Reference: [1](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ServerFaq).